# RecyclerView with different activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

What I have: A `RecyclerView` with pictures of places like bars, coffee stores, etc.

What I want: That when you click on one of these images I show you the info of the selected place

My question: How can i set the `OnCLickListener` for the third picture for example

Please, if you can explain with code it would be great, I am not good programming yet, so I would really appreciate

My adapter

```
    public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public AdapterDatos(ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listaLugares) {
        listalugares = listaLugares;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//esto es lo que hacereferencia al xml donde vamos a meter la info
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);//aqui le asignamos el valor del view al viewHolder
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {// este metodo es el que se encarga de establecer la conexion entre el adaptador y la clase Viewholder ( a la cual le asignamos el xml)
        holder.etiLugares.setText(listalugares.get(position).getLugares());// asi se asignan los textos
        holder.Foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());//asi se asignan las fotos


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {//este metodo va a decir el tamaño del viewHolder, en este caso de tamaño del array listalugares
        return listalugares.size();//se hace asi
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if(listener!= null){
            listener.onClick(view);
       }
  }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView etiLugares;
        ImageView Foto;
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            etiLugares = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);//esto hace referencia a los elementos donde queremos meter la info
            Foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);

        }
    }
}
```

My java class

```
    public class foodAndGo extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
    RecyclerView recyclerLugares;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_and_go);

        listalugares = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerLugares = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerID);
        recyclerLugares.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        llenarNombres();

        AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(listalugares);
        adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccion"+listalugares.get(recyclerLugares.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getLugares(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(foodAndGo.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
      recyclerLugares.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    private void llenarNombres() {
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Restaurantes", R.drawable.carnemejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Bares", R.drawable.beers));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Cafeterías",R.drawable.desayunosmejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Pizzerias",R.drawable.pizzaamejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Favoritos",R.drawable.favoritosmejo));


    }
}
```

Comment: So right now you must be able to open one Activity through your recyclerview item click event, is that so? And you want to open two more right?

Comment: `setClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder` and check if the `position == 3`

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why the answers don't work would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you apparently got your answer there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter's **onBindViewHolder** try this code:

```
holder.Foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
            if(position==0){
              Intent intent = new Intent(context,MapsActivity.class) // You can get context from onCreateViewHolder, initialize one from parent.getContext() or pass one in constructor of adapter
              startActivity(intent) 

            }else if(position==1){
             // open Second Activity
            }else{
             // open Third Activity
            }

        });
```

Comment: It doesn't let me implement the "startActivity" function

Comment: You can call startActivity function using context, which I already told how to usr context,  you can find it in comment in the code.

Comment: Thanks for keep answering my friend, but as i said, i am not good programming yet, i would really appreciate code example, sorry for my ignorance :( again, thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

> Attach a click listener on view

```
 holder.imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                          //Do Something
          }
```

Comment: It doesn't let me implement the "startActivity" function

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set onClick only for the third position from the List
Remove your  `view.setOnClickListener(this);` from `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//esto es lo que hacereferencia al xml donde vamos a meter la info
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);//aqui le asignamos el valor del view al viewHolder

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

set OnClick inside the `OnBindViewHolder` only for the Third position using if Statement

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {// este metodo es el que se encarga de establecer la conexion entre el adaptador y la clase Viewholder ( a la cual le asignamos el xml)
            holder.etiLugares.setText(listalugares.get(position).getLugares());// asi se asignan los textos
            holder.Foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());//asi se asignan las fotos
               if(holder.getAdapterPosition() == 3)
         holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // Parent ID

        }
```

Comment: It doesn't let me implement the "startActivity" function

Comment: Create Context context; Globally , then in your onCreateViewHolder  give this Line " context = parent.getContext(); "  Using context you can start Activity

Comment: you can get your context from onCreateViewHolder "parent.getContext()" you can call start activity using the context

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {//esto es lo que hacereferencia al xml donde vamos a meter la info
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);//aqui le asignamos el valor del view al viewHolder

            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {// este metodo es el que se encarga de establecer la conexion entre el adaptador y la clase Viewholder ( a la cual le asignamos el xml)
            holder.etiLugares.setText(listalugares.get(position).getLugares());// asi se asignan los textos
            holder.Foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());//asi se asignan las fotos
            if(position%3==0)
            holder.Foto.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```

Comment: It doesn't let me implement the "startActivity" function